# How to add java syntax highlighting to devtools in electron?

Tags: javascript, java, google-chrome-devtools, electron

I'm trying to debug my GWT app using java source maps (GWT SuperDevMode) but for some reason java syntax highlighting is not working.

When I open my app in Chrome the syntax highlighting works ok.

Is there a way to turn on java syntax highlighting in electron devtools?

Comment: are you talking about java or javascript syntax highligting? The question, tags, and context make it unclear.

Comment: I was talking about Java syntax highlighting. GWT loads Java source maps. When I load GWT app in Chrome - Java source is displayed and it is highlighted, in electron it's not highlighted.